# How do you format a datetime to am/pm, without periods, when using date-fns version 2.x?

Tags: javascript, date-fns

Version 2.x of the excellent date package `date-fns` only has these built-in am/pm formats.

[image: date-fns am pm formats]

How can I format the lower case am/pm without the periods?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can now use the `aaa` pattern for that case `(v.2.23.0)`.

[image]

Source: https://date-fns.org/v2.23.0/docs/format

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the info. I changed this to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 23):

### -- For datefns versions older than 2.23.0 --

#### Quick solution

Use `aaaaa'm'`:

```
format(new Date(), "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm aaaaa'm'")
```

**Explanation:** @GollyJer found a really clever way to work around this limitation. We can use `aaaaa` to yield `a` (for AM) or `p` (for PM) according to [the documentation](https://date-fns.org/v2.11.0/docs/format). Then we just follow it with the escaped character `m`, which is `'m'`, resulting in `am` or `pm`.

**Note:** this may result in a wrong output if you allow any kind of locale switching, because AM and PM may be different depending on the language.

#### Other ways

Nonetheless, for these versions, there's no **native¹** way of doing this, as per documentation and source code reviewing, because the formatting is dependent on the locale configuration as shown in the source code ([`_lib/format/formatters/index.js`](https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/blob/14b706ba79a5ce30913bf8700e32535b5c4645a9/src/_lib/format/formatters/index.js#L455)):

```
// AM or PM
a: function(date, token, localize) {
  var hours = date.getUTCHours()
  var dayPeriodEnumValue = hours / 12 >= 1 ? 'pm' : 'am'

  switch (token) {
    case 'a':
    case 'aa':
    case 'aaa':
      return localize.dayPeriod(dayPeriodEnumValue, {
        width: 'abbreviated',
        context: 'formatting'
  })
  // ...
```

<sup>**1:** by native, I mean a straightforward native API formatter.</sup>

You can [add a new locale](https://date-fns.org/v2.11.0/docs/I18n) to customize the strings though. This would imply changing this specific part (based on [`locale/en-US/_lib/localize/index.js`](https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/blob/14b706ba79a5ce30913bf8700e32535b5c4645a9/src/locale/en-US/_lib/localize/index.js#L98)):

```
var formattingDayPeriodValues = {
    // ...
    abbreviated: {
        am: 'AM',
        pm: 'PM',
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

It's sad this new version doesn't have a straightforward way of customizing the default locales, or even just a simple way to apply a monkey-patch. Creating a new locale isn't elegant at all and replacing `a.m.` with `am` manually after the call to `format` isn't either.

### Versions 1.x.x and 2.0.0 (alpha/beta)

For these versions, just use the `a` format. Example:

```js
console.log(dateFns.format(new Date(), 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm a'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/date-fns/1.30.1/date_fns.min.js"></script>
<!-- or: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/date-fns/2.0.0-alpha0/date_fns.min.js -->
```

You can check for yourself [in the source code](http://cdn.date-fns.org/v2.0.0-alpha0/date_fns.js) the way it works:

```
var meridiemLowercase = [
    'am',
    'pm'
];

var formatters = {
    // ...
    'a': function (date) {
        return date.getHours() / 12 >= 1 ? meridiemLowercase[1] : meridiemLowercase[0];
    },
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't even realize version 2 is fairly new. I've updated the question to reflect the new version which doesn't have the formatting from your answer with 1.x.

Comment: @GollyJer Edited the answer. Version 2 was also news for me. It seems to be working the same way so I don't know what the deal with the documentation is. `a` for `am`, `aa` for `a.m.` and `A` for `AM` etc... Edit: I now see there's a 2.11.0 version but not available on CDN, I'll check it out and get back to you.

Comment: I found a way to do this with 2.1+. Can you update your answer and I'll accept it. Thanks. `format(new Date(), "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm aaaaa'm'")`

Comment: It doesn't like capital A for AM.